# I am not getting push notifications on iOS. Device gets registered but no notifications received

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Azure. I register for notifications, get the APN token string and register that with Azure. I have added the p12 certificate to Azure and it worked. Push notifications are enabled for the App ID in the Apple developer settings site yet Xcode has a red circle with an exclamation mark inside it next to "Add the Push Notifications feature to your App ID". I did...

How do I make this work? It's working for Android.